# puppeteer - Inspecting POST request where payload is FormData

Tags: axios, puppeteer, form-data, jest-puppeteer

I have a process in React that looks something like this:

```
handleButtonClick() {
  const payload = new FormData();
  payload.append('foo', someFileBlobContent);
  axios.post('/my-api/', payload);
}
```

When a button is clicked, some data is compiled as FormData, then sent as the payload in a POST request to an API.

In my Jest/Puppeteer tests, I'm trying to confirm that the request contains the data that it should:

```
page.click('.my-button');

await page.waitForRequest(request => {
  if (request.url().match(/my-api/) && request.method() === 'POST') {
    expect(request.postData()).toBeDefined();
    return true;
  }
});
```

In this scenario `request.postData()` is `undefined`. Is there some way in Puppeteer to inspect the contents of a POST request where the payload is a `FormData` structure?

When running the process in Chrome, I can see the FormData displayed in the network requests via Chrome devtools, so I know the data is being sent, but I'd like to assert it.

Comment: IMHO, the code looks fine. Are you sure you are calling `postData()` on the correct request?

Comment: @ThomasDandorf, yea, pretty sure it's catching the right request. The `method()` and `url()` are as expected. I even logged all the matching requests without returning true, and only one request was sent with the correct method and url.

Comment: If you use `page.on('request', ...)` instead, is that able to return the postData? Can you maybe share more code or the page?

Comment: Tried using `page.on('request', ...)` and got the same result. I also swapped out the FormData with a regular JS object, and that data appeared in `postData()` just fine. However, that doesn't work so well in reality for uploading files programmatically which is why I am using FormData.

Seems to me like an issue with Puppeteer that they don't surface form data in any way. I'll create an issue on Puppeteer.

Comment: Indeed, `postData()` does not work for file uploads as they are `multipart/form-data` requests. I added an answer with a alternative that might work for you. Hope it's a "good enough" check for your use case. :)

Comment: Issue reported here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests, the `request.postData()` was only working for me on `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` forms (aka "normal form data"). As soon as you upload a file the `content-type` is `multipart/form-data` and puppeteer will not be able to return post data.

#### Alternative: Check the Content-Type header

As you cannot check if post data is send, you can still check if the request is actually a `multipart/form-data` request. In that case the `content-type` header looks like this `multipart/form-data; boundary=...`, so you can check it like this:

```js
await page.waitForRequest(request => {
  if (request.url().match(/my-api/) && request.method() === 'POST') {
    const headers = request.headers();
    expect(headers['content-type'].startsWith('multipart/form-data')).toBe(true);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Not quite what I want in the end, but it seems like this is about the closest I'll be able to get given the current state of Puppeteer.